# How to monitor AKS pod availability cpu and memory utilization?

Tags: azure

I want to monitoring the AKS pod availability, cpu and memory utilization. This is not available in the metrics. We want to run the query to get it. IS there any sample query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately pod CPU and memory metrics are currently not available for metrics explorer and current only way now is to use the log search alerts from Azure Monitor.

For that, you would have to enable Azure Monitor for containers as explained in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-onboard) onboard to Azure Monitor for containers document and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-alerts) you have queries to find the CPU and memory for containers in a deployment.

Just FYI, AFAIK the pod performance metrics will be added to Metrics Explorer in the near future. Current ETA for it is end of this month or early next month.

Comment: Krishna, would you know if the pod performance metrics are now available?